# Best way to find the smallest value from a table?

Tags: sorting, lua

```lua
local test = {10,104,20,1042,1042104,592,502,5940,230952,291}

for i, v in pairs(test) do
  table.sort(test)
  print(v)
end
```

I'm printing out those values successfully, but I'm not sure how to print just the smallest number. I've already tried using math.min to no avail.

I tried `math.min`, and attempted to use `table.unpack`, but none of that has worked. Using math.min resulted in nothing changing, and using table.unpack resulted in it printing just the first number before showing an error:

```
10
lua: main.lua:6: attempt to call field 'unpack' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    main.lua:6: in main chunk
```

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to get the smallest value is to run over the table once and remember the smallest value you find.

```
local min = math.huge
for i, v in ipairs(test) do
  min = v < min and v or min
  -- or:  min = math.min(v, min)
end
```

Or `local min = math.min(table.unpack(test))` Note that unpack is limited to some thousand values in older Lua versions.

Sorting is more complex. For small datasets its usually ok though.

Why would you sort the table in a loop btw?

```
for i, v in pairs(test) do table.sort(test) print(v) end
```

Move `table.sort(test)` in front of the loop

Regarding `table.unpack`, use `unpack`. You're probably running an old version of Lua. I belive it was moved into the table library after 5.1

Comment: `unpack` is limited by the stack size. On 5.1 that's indeed about 1.6 thousands (about 65k on LuaJIT tho). Newer Lua versions have a stack size of about one million though.